Jackson handle 2 properties with the same name
I'm using retrofit and Jackson to deserialaze XML from body.
The third-party Api returns me xml of the form
<Answer>
  <Seance Hall="auditorium">
    <Hall>
      <Sector />
      <Sector />
      ...
    </Hall>
  </Seance>
</Answer>

As you can see "Hall" apeared twice in XML, as property of Seance and as a nested element. I need to create class for deserialization this XML.
I've created class for deserialization:
public class SeanceResponse {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String hall;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Hall")
  @JacksonXmlText
  private HallResponse hallResponse;
}


public class HallResponse {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Sector")
  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  private List<SectorResponse> sectors = new ArrayList<>();


As you might expect I'm getting an error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Multiple fields representing property "Hall": SeanceResponse#hall vs SeanceResponse#hallResponse
Is there any way to handle such a case?
